# Program cannot acquire the capabilities it needs (raw sockets)

Tags: linux, debian, socket, capabilities

Note: This is partly a programming question, but my gut feeling is that this has more to do with the Linux' security capabilities framework *in general*, hence posting here instead of StackOverflow.

I have a program that needs to use the `cap_net_raw` capability for raw sockets & packet capture; The system I'm using is Debian 11 with Linux 5.16.0-6-amd64.

I've granted the capability (with `cap_net_admin`) to the binary

```
% sudo /sbin/setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' ./program
```

(Side note: I've granted my user the `cap_setfcap` capability in `/etc/security/capability.conf`, but I still cannot `setcap` without sudo)

and confirmed the caps being applied at least almost as requested

```
% /sbin/getcap ./program
./program cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip
```

The `capsh --print` output for bash running as my user shows

```
% /sbin/capsh --print
Current: cap_setpcap,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_setfcap=i
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
Ambient set =
Current IAB: cap_setpcap,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_setfcap
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=1001(johndoe) euid=1001(johndoe)
gid=1001(johndoe)
groups=27(sudo),1001(johndoe)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

Now; I can run ping with my user with no problems. On Debian ping seems to be capability aware, i.e. the binary has required capability

```
% /sbin/getcap `which ping`
/usr/bin/ping cap_net_raw=ep
```

And from the `ping` source code (https://sources.debian.org/src/iputils/3%3A20210202-1/ping/ping.c/) I see there's no elevation of capabilities at runtime. I.e. the file capabilities are enough to make it work as intended. My conclusion is that my program should work equally well as long as the executable file has the proper capability in place.

But it doesn't seem to be that way. I have set the required (as far as I can tell) capability to my program file, but when I run it, the socket creation fails with `EPERM`.

Debugging the process and breaking at the socket creation and checking the process capabilities shows that the process doesn't have the required capabilities in effect:

```
 % grep Cap /proc/`pidof program`/status                     
CapInh: 0000000080083100
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000 
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

Checking the `CapInh` and `CapBnd` with `capsh --decode=...` shows those bits are as expected (matches with the earlier `capsh --print` output). But the permitted set and effective set (`CapPrm` and `CapEff` respectively) are not what I expected them to be (Perhaps my exceptions are just plain wrong). I assumed the permitted set would have `cap_net_raw` and `cap_net_admin`.

In order to fix the situation, I tried enabling the `cap_net_raw` in my program, before creating the socket:

```
cap_value_t needed[] = { CAP_NET_RAW };
cap_t caps = cap_get_proc();

cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, std::size(needed), needed, CAP_SET);
if (cap_set_proc(caps))
{
    // handle failure
}
```

But this fails miserably (`EPERM`), as "expected" by now. Tried also adding the bit into `CAP_PERMITTED` first, but the result from `cap_set_proc()` for that modification is again `EPERM`.

What am I missing or have misunderstood here? What else do I need to do in order to enable raw socket access for my program?

Does Debian 11 have stricter rules & restrictions compared to other systems?

For reference: I checked a system with Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 10) that I have at my disposal, and there `capsh` reported the `pi` user's `Current` set to be the same as the `Bounding` set (and there was no `Ambient` set at all). Afaik, the system is running with defaults, so my conclusion is that Raspberry Pi OS/Debian 10 has by default more permissible/relaxed security model when it comes to capabilities.

Does this have something to do with namespaces? File ownership/permissions?

Comment: Is your `./program` setuid or setgid?

Comment: Neither, at least I haven't set those bits. Nor see I them set on system binaries.

Comment: Right, I didn’t mean to say it should be, I wanted to check that it wasn’t (since that can affect capabilities too).

Comment: Your question reminded me about one thing; During Debian installation there was a question about  the `setuid`/`setgid` & `sticky` bits with "Yes / No" type switch. Don't remember exactly what it was about, perhaps should they be stored in the inode or elsewhere, or something. Cannot remember what I chose for that either. Hopefully I didn't break anything with that.

Comment: If `ping` works, you haven’t broken anything.

Comment: It shouldn’t make a difference, but have you tried `+ep` instead of `+eip`?

Comment: Yes, did try with `+ep`, no change. Still have no clue what the root cause is, but on another Debian box (a virtual machine, Linux 5.10.x) the same code/setup works fine, so I guess I'm going to reinstall the 5.16.x machine/redo from scratch.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that `/home` is mounted with `nosuid` option and I was building & running from a git checkout that resides in my home directory. 

(Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099797/raw-capture-capabilities-cap-net-raw-cap-net-admin-not-working-outside-usr-b)

Comment: You can do a bind (remount) to allow on a sub-directory.